# Python regex, how-to group an item within a regex

Tags: python, regex, grouping

I'm having trouble creating a regex.
Here is a sample of the text on which the regex should work:

---

```
<b>Additional Equipment Items</b> <br>
40001 <br>
1  Battery Marathon L (8 cells type L6V110) <br>
40002 <br>
```

---

What I now want to select is >>1<< and >>Battery Marathon L (8 cells type L6V110)<<.

Therefore I have produced the following Regex:

```
found = re.findall('<b>.*Items\s*<\/b>\s*<br>(?:\s*[1-4]0[0-9][0-9][0-9] <br>\s*(\d*) (.*) <br>)*', content)
```

Seems like the outer regex does match, but the inner groups are empty :(

Any suggestions?!

Comment: Bad idea to parse using regex. Use html parsers.

Comment: Well... maybe. Based on the sample provided, this is not really full-blown parsing, it's extracting data from a regular, repeating structure, which regexes are generally good at, plus there's no issue with nested tags (which is the thing that really makes regexes incapable of parsing HTML). So as a quick-and-dirty solution, a regex match might be okay here. (Of course a stream parser would be a fine choice too)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me, on Python 2.6.5

Comment: @Gopi: A HTML parser like beautiful soup won't work here since the HTML code is completely unstructured (its actually a PDF converted to HTML).

@David Zaslavsky: I use the same python version and also checked the expression on http://www.pythonregex.com/. And the findall() result are four empty groups :(

Comment: Oh David you are right. The example which I have posted really works. Nevertheless it does not work on this original text: <b>Additional Equipment Items</b> <br>
40001 <br>
1  Battery Marathon L (8 cells type L6V110) <br>
40002 <br>
                   <br>
40003 <br>
                   <br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I sometimes just hate Regex. Some whitespaces owned me...

Here is the solution:

```
<b>.*Items\s*<\/b>\s*<br>(?:\s*[1-4]0[0-9][0-9][0-9] <br>\s*(\d*)\s*(.*) <br>)
```